# Macos WKWebView only gets partial content

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am trying to use a Macos WKWebView to get the text content of a Facebook page. However, the WKWebView's load method only gets a small part of the Facebook page: I need to scroll down manually several dozen times in order to get more and more content. How can I automatize the process to load the full page?

```
func getPageContent(url: URL) {
   let urlRequest = URLRequest (url:url)
   myWebView.load(urlRequest)
   myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML;") { (result,error) in
     if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
     } else {
        // grab text
        rawHtml = result as! String
        // rawHtml contains only a small part of the page!
   }
}
```

Comment: there's no "full page" in case of facebook or similar apps. They use "infinite scrolling", which means when you get to the bottom of the currently available data, they make an XHR call to get more data. Here's a similar question for Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858241/retrieve-html-content-from-an-infinite-scroll-page-facebook and the right advice to use Facebook API, rather than try to hack Facebook page

Comment: Thanks Kiril. Using Facebook's API Graph looks daunting (tokens, OAuth etc.) for what I need... Is there a way to ask a WKWebView to scroll down 10 times automatically before loading its content?